# Determine key combination based on current keyboard layout

Tags: java

Assume, I know my current keyboard's locale setting (there seems to be `InputContext.getInstance().getLocale()` for that), is there a way to determine programmatically which keys on the keyboard would need to be pressed to type a specific character?

**Example:**

- Keyboard layout: German, Mac
- Input: `õ`
- Result: `[alt-down, n-down, n-up, alt-up, o-down, o-up]`

**Background:** I'm wondering if it's possible to make usage of the [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class more portable.